# App that always records in background

Tags: android, audio-recording

I would like an app that automatically records all audio while the phone is on.

This app should not quit or exit for any reason and not pause except when I'm on the phone. My phone runs Android 7, and I want to record public area (not phone calls).

Ideally I want this to record offline somewhere as not to fill up my phone.

Comment: Should it record until it has used all of memory? At, say 80% of memory, or X hours, should it start to overwrite the oldest with new recording? Btw, you might want to get advice from https://law.stackexchange.com/ because in many places recording someone without their permission can get you into ***serious*** legal trouble.

Comment: Ideally I want it to record to google photos or music as not fill up the space on my phone.  Legally where I live this is allowed.

Comment: If you want it to record to Google, nit your 'phone, please update your question. If you don't tell us what you want, we can't really guess. Some, like me, might ask questions; others not.  The more detail you give, the more we can help you.

Comment: Honestly I don't need it to record to google but I would think it would make sense not to fill up the phone

Comment: And the app will need to take care not to fill up Google :-)  Seriously, if you record for a year, they are going to cancel your account. Your best bet is one that constantly has the last X minutes.

Comment: You could stream to Youtube. I think there's a 3-4 hrs limit after which it will start discarding the old video (i.e. not store it).

Comment: @laggingreflex better have unlimited data then and hope you don't get throttled.